# php web service e-social

Tags: php

Olá, alguém já fez algo com php que acessa o web service do e-social? Estou com dificuldades em entender o que é a cadeia de certificação. Não será possível por exemplo utilizar uma aplicação desenvolvida em php para acessar o e-social, terá que ser uma aplicação local, desenvolvida por exemplo em C# e outros?

Comment: Acho qud "cadeia de certificação" se refere a  entidades certificadoras que emitem certificado digital tipo e-cpf, e-cnpj, certificados de sites.

Comment: Estou pensando nisso, e não estou achando nenhuma solução.
Veja estou vendo em php como se acessa um webservice, pelo que pude ver,  podemos usar o SOAP para isso, mas ainda tenho algumas dúvidas. 
Será que caso eu tenha que usar o SOAP para tal, a maquina que eu estiver acessando o webservice eu teria que colocar esses certificados

Comment: sim, você iria pegar a chave privada desse certificado e assinar os dados que iria enviar. Pesquise sobre assinatura digital para entender esse processo.

Comment: esse processo e semelhante a emitir nota fiscal. Dica para entender o processo. https://youtu.be/v1rByVX1_FY